# How do I parse HTML non-class items in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing

```
                    <div id="dump-list">    
<div class="dump-row"> 
 <div class="dump-location odd" data-jmapping="{id: 35, point: {lng: -73.00898601, lat: 41.71727402}, category: 'office'}">

    <div class="SingleLinkNoTx">
    <a href="#10" class="loc-link">Acme Software</a><br/><strong>John Doe, MBA</strong><br/>123 Main St.<br />New York, NY 10036<br /><strong class="telephone">(212) 555-1234</strong><br/>
    </div><!-- END.SingleLinkNoTx -->

    <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" class="web_link">Visit Website</a><span><br />(0.3 miles)</span>   
    <div class="loc-info">
             <div class="loc-info-text ">
        John Doe, MBA<br /><a href="http://maps.google.com/?daddr=41.71727402,-73.00898601" target="_blank">Get Directions &raquo;</a>    
         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

How is the above HTML parsed in PHP, so that non-class fields such as the company name, person's name (John Doe, MBA), address, city, state zip code can be separated to their own variable using xpath? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something among the lines of:

```
$xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="loc-link"]//text()');
```

`$xpath` is the xpath object with all the dom information, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). The evaluate function returns the content for the requested expression.

The expression `//a[@class="loc-link"]//text()` tell xpath to look for any anchor `a` with the class attribute set to `loc-link` then within the anchor look for any (nested) textnode.

Comment: Can you explain how this works and what the role of evaluate performs here? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer with the requested explanation

Comment: OK. Is something special needed to parse the '<br/>' ? I tried 'br' in place of the 'a', but that didn't work for me. Thanks!